# How can I show text on the form and can make it a link pointing to some URL in django

Tags: python, django, forms

Currently I am using django and working with Forms. I just need to show some dynamic text without any fields from the form rather than from the template. For Example. like in html it can be done by

some text

, but how can we write this text from django form, as it is dynamic and I cannot put it on template straight away.

It can be very stupid question but I am really struggling with it being a newbie.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can access variables in the template with

```
{{variable}}
```

For Details, see the documentation at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#basics

Comment: Thanks for info, but actually there are dynamic RadioFields after that are dependent on that dynamic text and I am accessing the form in the template using {{form}}. So it is not very straight forward. I have to show a plain text.

Comment: If you look at the example at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial04/, you see that they use a for loop on a variable. You can easily set the list of possible choices for a radio button in the python code.